# Logical Device Name assigned to Physical NIC mapping

Tags: linux, interface

I'm looking for a scripted solution that will show which logical network interfaces are mapped to which physical NICs.

That is, if a server has 2+ interfaces and 2+ NICs, how do I know which NIC contains which interface?  i.e., the ethX interface is mapped to the underlying ______ NIC hardware.

The closest I can get right now involves using two commands and then comparing the results.  I'm striving for the most generic *nix commands as I want these to work across a broad swath of Linux installations without relying on any additional installed tools/packages.  ( Typically, I have no rights or permission to install anything)

Command 1 returns the interface name and the MAC address.  MAC addresses are typically immutable, so they provide a solid reference point.  The interface name is a label, and is gathered for reference

```
> ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
        link/ether 14:18:77:27:c1:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
        link/ether 14:18:77:27:c1:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: sci0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
        link/ether 14:18:77:27:c1:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
        link/ether 14:18:77:27:c1:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Command 2:

```
>lspci -vd ::0200
    
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
        Subsystem: Dell Device 1f5b
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 55, NUMA node 0
        Memory at 91b30000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Memory at 91b40000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Memory at 91b50000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Expansion ROM at 92700000 [disabled] [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=17 Masked-
        Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 00-00-14-18-77-27-c1-32
        Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: tg3
        Kernel modules: tg

01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
        Subsystem: Dell Device 1f5b
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 57, NUMA node 0
        Memory at 91b00000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Memory at 91b10000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Memory at 91b20000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Expansion ROM at 92740000 [disabled] [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=17 Masked-
        Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 00-00-14-18-77-27-c1-33
    ...
```

From these two outputs I can map the interface on eth0 to the physical NIC, using the interface MAC Address and the Device Serial Number.

Is there a more direct method to see this?

We need a scripting method to handle this as a remote discovery.

Due to some limitations, the command cannot use any piping of output.  So no grep, awk, etc.  We can truncate and compare the results in code.

Thank you.

Comment: The question is confusing. In context, "NIC" (_**N**_ etwork _**I**_ nterface _**C**_ ard)  and "physical _interface_" are the same thing. Do you mean to map the MAC and/or IP addresses? Map the NIC to it's PCI bus ID? Or something else?

Comment: eth0, eth1, ethX is a logical definition of the network interface.  At some level, it is connected to a physical network card. n a computer with more than one physical NIC, how to tell from the Command line which interface (eth0, eth1, etc) is connected to which card?

Another way to phrase it.  Suppose I have a computer with 2 NICs.  One is a Broadcom NIC, the other is HP.  The computer has two interfaces defined on it.   Eth0 and Eth1.   Without physically accessing the machine, how do I determine which logical interface is defined on which physical NIC?

Comment: Maybe asked this way?   From the command line, how do you tell what the underlying hardware is for an interface?   eth0 uses the ________ underlying hardware.

Comment: Edit your question to include those clarifications, so others wanting to help can see it right away without having to dig through the comments. What you really want, however, is how to determine which _logical device name_ is assigned to which _physical NIC_. And that is a bit more complex as it may not always be stable across reboots. So I will leave that for a more formal answer -- Right now, I'm just trying to help you ask the "right" question to obtain the right answer. :-)

Comment: Also, include in your edits which OS you are using. Many modern Linux-based OSes have changes to using predictable device names, such as my Wi-Fi NIC is "wlp3s2", indicating "wireless lan pci-express bus 3 slot 2". That will remain "stable" as long as I do nothing to change the bus/slot of the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the important feedback.  I've updated and clarified the question a bit more.  Appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the information in the `/sys` filesystem. My box is not using "predictable device names", but here is what you see on my system:

```
$ ll /sys/class/net
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul 14 18:26 eth0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:06:00.0/net/eth0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul 14 18:26 lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul 14 18:26 wlan0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/net/wlan0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul 14 18:26 wlan1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan1
```

So you can see directly which interfaces belong to which physical cards by following the symlinks.

If you don't need this particular mapping, but a different one, look around the `/sys` filesystem and see if you find a better one.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly the type of command I was looking for.  I can map the 06:00.0 portion of the link to the lspci -vd ::0200 output to see the Ethernet controller name

Comment: Note that `lspci` uses a database to match vendor and device id to the "Ethernet controller name" (and this database may change). For scripts, you could just use the vendor and device id directly, and get this from the `/sys` file system as well.